# How to declare a function taking named arguments with an interface?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

How to declare a function taking named arguments with an interface when using babel?

No errors are revealed by Intellisense however, as soon as Babel compiles it, I get an error which comes [from here in @babel/parser](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/d2971a1959775d86cbf954bc4b22ee4a6595c6a8/packages/babel-parser/src/plugins/typescript.js#L327)

> Name in a signature must be an Identifier

```ts
declare namespace ServerPlugin {
    interface MyFunction {
        ({ next, extendSchema, extendDatabase }: Params): void;
        displayName?: string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that babel doesn't want us to be that accurate regarding named types.

So instead of describing each of the named arguments, one unnamed arguments that wraps them all does the same job.

```ts
declare namespace ServerPlugin {
    interface MyFunction {
        (args: Params): void;
        displayName?: string;
    }

    interface Params {
        req: Express.Request;
        res: Express.Response;
        next: NextFunction;
        extendDatabase: ExtendDatabase;
        extendSchema: ExtendSchema;
    }
}
```